# Should a question about Winter Bash be un-locked?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, meta, locked-posts

In the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag I found this locked question from december 2015:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313692/how-can-i-leave-the-current-winter-bash

I don't recall its history but seeing the few comments (edit history) on it and the question being locked by a moderator within 20 minutes after posting I see something had been unfolding there.

As the question doesn't seem to be worth keeping around (score: +1/-14) nor do I fancy writing an answer for it, shouldn't that question be unlocked so the community can use their close votes on it?

If not, can the mod team add a notice why that post has to stay in that state.

Comment: I think it was locked because of the roll back war there.

Comment: I was sure such locks had timeouts...

Comment: Did you try flagging it?  Something like "Unlock this so the Roomba can take out the trash.", etc.

Comment: @BrockAdams I did not try that yet. I assumed that the content-dispute should be solved on meta first.

Comment: @Braiam They don't.

Comment: @dorukayhan they can have automatic timeouts - it appears I just didn't use that option in this case...

Comment: Anyway - it's unlocked now... it's presumably been mostly forgotten about and isn't going to attract a rollback war at this stage in its life...

Comment: It's deleted now.